# Bash loops to search for all columns

Tags: bash, loops

I have a huge file of 200,000 rows and 8k columns and looking to loop or if statement in shell to extract the value '0/1' from each column one by one (column wise) and print that column along with first two columns with header as well.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, please do show us sample Input and expected output in code tags please.

Comment: Depending on how your data are formatted, you could just use the `cut` unix tool, to pull out whatever column you are interested in.

Comment: Something like `cut -f1,3,4 -d',' data.csv` would return the 1st,3rd,and 4th columns, splitting on a comma.

Comment: Hi Guys thanks for answer.... Please note i have multiple value i need to filter only '0/1' value than print that cloumn along with others. I cannot specify column 1 to 8000 to find a value and cut?

Comment: Then you will need to write a program to go through your file to figure out which columns it needs, and then to actually print those out.

Comment: Yes exactly you are write , current this command is giving me desired output awk  ' NR ==1 ||  $3 == "0/1"  {print $1"\t"$2"\t"$3 }' test_aw.txt . But i want that it do through each column and than print 0/1 along with first three columns and header,

Answer (score 0):

With `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==1{split($0,arr,/ /)};
     NR>1{for (i=3;i<=NF;i++) if($i=="0/1") print $1, $2, $i, arr[i]}' OFS="\t" infile
```

For the below sample input data:

```
A B C D E F G H I J K
1 2 0/1 4 5 0/1 7 8 9 0/1 10
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0/1
```

The output would be:

```
1       2       0/1     C
1       2       0/1     F
1       2       0/1     J
0       1       0/1     K
```

Comment: Thx. i want this  example for input and output file. Remember i have 8000 column so i cannot specify column name                                                              Input:                                        
Chr Pos  Sample1 Sample2 Sample3
1 568478 0/1 1/1 0/1
15 985612 0/0 0/1 1/1
4 412587 0/1 0/1 0/0
5 218663 0/0 0/1 1/1
Out put 

Chr Pos           Sample1 Sample2 Sample3
1 568478   0/1         N/A         0/1
15 985612   N/A 0/1         N/A
4 412587   0/1         0/1         N/A
5 218663   N/A 0/1         N/A